# Any way to debug an Oracle Sequence?

Tags: oracle, sequence

Somewhere in a large project a sequence is being incremented one too many times. Is there some way to add a trigger or watch to the sequence when `.NEXTVAL` is invoked so we can get a call stack and see where it's happening?

I tried looking for all the code that accesses the sequence directly, as well as code that constructs queries with `.NEXTVAL` and none are relevant.

Pretty sure it's on the database side because we've trapped the execution as much as we can, and the sequence is being incremented after an `INSERT` so maybe some post-insert trigger in a package we can't see.

Comment: Did you check view `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`? There you may find it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's embedded in PL/SQL either directly or within a non-dynamic SQL executed by PL/SQL *and* that's a stored program (not anonymous), you can find it as Wernfried mentioned in `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`.

If it's an anonymous (non-stored) PL/SQL block, you'd have to search the code in `sql_fulltext` in `gv$sqlarea` for the name and hope it's still in the pool.

If however it's called from a *SQL* statement (whether standalone or from PL/SQL), it should be **visible in the SQL plan data**.

For recent SQL still in the pool:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM gv$sql_plan
  WHERE object_name = 'MYSEQUENCE_NAME'
    AND operation = 'SEQUENCE'
```

For aged-out SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_hist_sql_plan
 WHERE object_name = 'MYSEQUENCE_NAME'
   AND operation = 'SEQUENCE'
```

Once you get the `sql_id` you can use that to query `gv$sqlarea` for the parsing user or `gv$active_session_history` for various other session details (executing user, program, module, machine, PL/SQL program (if any), etc..). About the only thing that lacks is the client process and osuser. If you found it in `dba_hist...` then you'll need to use `dba_hist_sqlstat` and `dba_hist_active_sess_history` for these details (which unfortunately, as it only stored 1 out of every 10 records from the in-memory sampling, is less likely to find the activity if it was relatively short-lived). Even the in-memory data might miss it if it was sub-second and not repeated. But this is what I'd do before resorting to anything more invasive.

Also ensure that the behavior you are witnessing isn't due to the sequence's `CACHE` setting.